# Finding an $st$-path in a planar graph which is adjacent to the fewest number of faces

Tags: algorithms, graphs, reference-request

I am curious whether the following problems has been studied before, but wasn't able to find any papers about it:

> Given a planar graph $G$, and two vertices $s$ and $t$, find an
>   $s$-$t$ path $P$ which minimizes the number of distinct faces of $G$
>   containing vertices of $P$ on their boundaries.

Does anybody know any references?

Comment: This may be a silly question, but would you need to fix an embedding for this?

Comment: @G.Bach: from an algorithmic point of view, when we say "given a planar graph", we usually mean "given a combinatorial map for a graph", hence the embedding is indeed fixed.

Comment: Do you have an application in mind, or just curiosity?

Comment: which research databases have you searched?

Comment: @zarathustra: No, if we say "given a planar graph" we mean "given a planar graph". If we assume that this graph is equipped with a combinatorial embedding we say, "given a plane graph". Of course, if the graph is 3-connected then the combinatorial embedding is fixed up to a global reflection.

Comment: @A.Schulz: please give a reference for this distinction.  Anyway, the question is meaningful only when an embedding is given.

Comment: @zarathustra you need only go to Wikipedia for this distinction.

Comment: It might be a silly question, but does the required metric (sum of number of faces) change with different embeddings of the given graph?

Comment: @codeR It's a good question. But yes, this number may change for a certain path. Let $G = (\{\,0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\,\}, \{\,\{\,0, 1\,\}, \{\,1, 2\,\}, \{\,1, 3\,\}, \{\,1, 4\,\}, \{\,2, 5\,\}, \{\,3, 5\,\}, \{\,4, 5\,\}, \{\,5, 6\,\}\,\})$. Let consider path $P = 0, 1, 2, 5, 6$. If both $0$ and $6$ belong to the same face as $2$, then $P$ touches $2$ of $3$ faces only. Otherwise it touches all $3$ faces. Also both the optimal path and the number of faces in the answer may change as well, but my example is too big for a comment