# Closed walk in planar graphs that contains $k$ faces

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, planar-graphs

**Input**: Planar graph $G$ and its embedding in sphere $\Pi$, edges $e, f \in E(G)$ and integer $k$.

**Output**: A shortest closed walk (one among possibly many, if exists) in $G$ using $e$ and $f$ which contains exactly $k$ faces of $G$.

A walk $w = v_1,e_1,v_2,...,e_i,v_i$ (where $v_j \in V(G), e_j \in E(G)$ for $1 \le j \le i$) uses an edge $e$, if $e = e_j$ for some $1 \le j \le i$. Also a walk $w$ contains the face $g$ if in the embedding of $G$ on sphere when we consider $w$ and $g$ as closed $2$-dimensional polytopes, then $g \subseteq w$.  A walk is allowed to have repeated vertices/edges.

Can this problem be solved in polynomial time?

Comment: 3. Regardless of how you obtained $G$, I still wonder whether it might be fruitful to consider $G^*$ (the [dual graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Other_facts_and_definitions) of $G$) and try to reformulate the problem in terms of $G^*$, and see if that leads to a clean formulation.  4. It might be useful to edit the question to clear up all of these.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19137/9550